# iterating in groups resulted by a group by SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

is there any way to iterate in groups grouped by a select statement?

```
      $bidsInPeriod = DB::table('bids')
        ->select('bundle_id','owner_id','target','bid', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
        ->where('submit_time','<',$i)
        ->whereRaw('? + run_time < deadline_time', array($i-3600))
        ->where('owner_id',$this->userId)
        ->where('status',0)
        ->groupBy('bundle_id')->get();
    foreach($bidsInPeriod as $bundle){
        $tmpBundle=new bundle($bundle['bundle_id'],$bundle['bid']);
        $bidRecords=bidsM::where('bundle_id','=',$i)->get();
        foreach($bidRecords as $bid){
            $tmpBundle->addBid($bid);
        }
```

Comment: please add DBMS you are using

Comment: it's innoDB i think.

Comment: If you want to go through the records that make up each group, then don't group, just order.

Comment: you mean there is no other way to do that?